# Using categorical encoding across multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sparse-matrix, categorical-data

I have a DataFrame X_Train with two categorical columns and a numerical column, for example:

| A | B | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'a1' | 'b1' | 0.5 |
| 'a1' | 'b2' | -0.8 |
| 'a2' | 'b2' | 0.1 |
| 'a2' | 'b3' | -0.2 |
| 'a3' | 'b4' | 0.4 |

Before sending this into a sklearn's linear regression, I change it into a sparse matrix. To do that, I need to change the categorical data into numerical indexes like so:

```
X_Train['acat'] = pd.factorize(X_Train['A'])[0]
X_Train['bcat'] = pd.factorize(X_Train['B'])[0]
```

Then I change it into a sparse matrix:

```
X_Train_Sparse = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((X_Train.N, (X_Train.acat, X_Train.bcat)))
```

I have another similar DataFrame, X_Test, for example:

| A | B | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'a4' | 'b3' | 0.6 |
| 'a5' | 'b5' | -0.1 |
| 'a6' | 'b2' | -0.1 |
| 'a6' | 'b1' | -0.5 |
| 'a6' | 'b3' | 0.3 |

I also need to change this to a sparse matrix. How do I use the same bcat categorization from X_Train for X_Test so that the linear regression treats 'b1' in X_Train as the same variable as 'b1' in X_Test? Implicit in this is that, if there is any B value in X_Test that is not in X_Train, this B value should be dropped because there was no learning from this B value so no prediction can be made from it.

Comment: You have multiple questions in one question, better split those up and create a new question for each subquestion, e.g. the sparse matrix part.

Comment: Thanks! but the sparse matrix part was not a question. I only gave it as an explanation for why I need the encoding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to apply the categorical encoding in advance of splitting:

**Sample:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: "'a1'",  1: "'a1'",  2: "'a2'",  3: "'a2'",  4: "'a3'",  5: "'a4'",  6: "'a5'",  7: "'a6'",  8: "'a6'",  9: "'a6'"}, 'B': {0: "'b1'",  1: "'b2'",  2: "'b2'",  3: "'b3'",  4: "'b4'",  5: "'b3'",  6: "'b5'",  7: "'b2'",  8: "'b1'",  9: "'b3'"}, 'N': {0: 0.5,  1: -0.8,  2: 0.1,  3: -0.2,  4: 0.4,  5: 0.6,  6: -0.1,  7: -0.1,  8: -0.5,  9: 0.3}})
```

**Code:**

```
# Encode categories
df['B'] = pd.Categorical(df['B'])
# Split data into train/test
df_train, df_test = df.iloc[:5], df.iloc[5:]
```

**Result:**

```
df_train['B'].cat.codes

Out[58]: 
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
dtype: int8

df_test['B'].cat.codes

Out[59]: 
5    2
6    4
7    1
8    0
9    2
dtype: int8
```

Comment: Thanks! In my application, the train and test are already separate. To implement your solution, I can merge them, generate the categorical, and split them again. I will try that.

Comment: @JafarSadeq, let me know if it worked and if it answered feel free to upvote and accept the answer, this will help future readers and give me a few points. Happy Coding!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a noob. Yes it definitely solved it. I accepted the answer but my votes don't count yet. Thanks again!